# Redirect non-www to www with aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: express, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk and I've followed the instructions to deploy my app using the express web server as follow:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

This setup uses nginx and route 53.

Everything works well, but now I'm trying to redirect from non-www/non-https URLs to "https://www.domain.com" (always https with www).

I've seen different solutions out there that either aren't working or seem hacky. What's the proper way to do this from the `aws console`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a S3 bucket that redirects naked domain to www. It is explained here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

You can redirect http to https by using Cloudfront. You can read more information here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html

You can setup the webserver on your EC2 instances to redirect as well, but that requires that you setup up your SSL certificate as well. It is easier to let AWS handle that with Cloudfront.

You are probably using Apache so it would be something like this.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs 
   Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /app/directory/
   SSLEngine On
   # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then setup your SSL certificate with LetsEncrypt in your deploy script.

Answer (score 7):

There's an easy way to do this.

1. Go to your Load Balancer
2. Select your LB
3. Click LISTENERS tab
4. Click under Rules -> view/edit rules
5. Add another rule

- Condition -> Host Header: yoursite.com
- Add Action -> Redirect to:
- HTTPS -> #{port}
- CUSTOM HOST, PATH, QUERY
- Host: [www.yoursite.com](http://www.yoursite.com)
- leave everything as is and 301 header

7. SAVE and you are good to go!

Everything will be redirected to your WWW url.

More explained here: https://channaly.medium.com/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-and-http-to-https-in-amazon-elasticbeanstalk-using-route53-and-alb-1098d54903c8

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the NGINX (or Apache) reverse proxy directly.

This elastic beanstalk document, in the reverse proxy configuration section, shows how you can add or modify the deployed NGINX config files:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

This post provides a good example for handling the redirects properly in nginx:

https://serverfault.com/a/1141240/104252

This is a link to the currently recommendeded nginx tls setup:

https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

and this shows how you can deploy the certs and keys from s3 to your ec2 instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html