# AWS : Redirecting www to root using Route 53 and S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an application that runs on a Elastic BeanStalk under a Classic Load balancer. I want my site to respond to example.com and also to www.example.com. I did the following to perform that :

### 1. Creating an A record to Classic Load Balancer

- In Route 53, I created a HostedZone called example.com and the created a A record for example.com as an alias to the Classic Load Balancer.

This works fine.

### 2. Creating a S3 Bucket for www.example.com

- I created a S3 Static web site Bucket named www.example.com that redirects to example.com

This works fine. When I navigate to http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com it redirects me to example.com

### 3. Creating a A record for www.example.com

- I created then a A Alias record named www.example.com to the S3 Bucket and waited for more than 16 hours.

This does not work. In Chrome, i have  the following error :

***This site can’t be reached www.example.com took too long to respond.***

What am I missing ?

PS: I have done nothing for www.example.com in my registrar. Anything have to be done ?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like its setup OK. Have your cleared your browser cache? Also can you post a picture of your route 53 setup (block out your domain if you prefer privacy)?

Comment: I cleared the browser cache. I added the Route 53 Setup

Comment: I was just looking into this further. Will hold fire pending the AWS incident.

Comment: I removed my edit because the issue has a CLOSED status. So it should work now... but still having the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169678/discussion-between-stu-and-radouane-roufid).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. What worked for me from discussion in that chat:

1. make sure that it's reachable via http
2. if yes - order an SSL Certificate and use CloudFront to be able to use https

if not - configuration of Alias / A-record is incorrect. Then check all permissions (S3 should be available for reading publicly; S3 bucket should be setup as Website Hosting; the bucket name should be identical to the Route 53 hosted zone name). See all details in official AWS article [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

Answer (score 0):

S3 Website endpoint doesn't support HTTPS so if a user access it on HTTPS, it won't work.
Creating a CloudFront only for redirection can solve this but increase the work.
(CF+ACM+S3+Route53)
I would suggest use a redirection rule directly on the beanstalk environment and create alias records for both www.example.com and example.com to point to ELB.

[Here](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-cloudfront/) is how you can do that using CloudFront

Directly on [Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669583/redirect-non-www-to-www-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk)